# writing specs for file validation using rspec(ruby project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this two test cases fail,

```
describe 'validations' do
  it { should validate_presence_of :file }
  it { should validate_presence_of :save_path }
end
```

This is the class i am testing for,

```
class ConvertFileToPdf < Base
  attr_accessor(
    :file,
    :save_path
  )
  validates_presence_of(
    :file,
    :save_path
  )

  def path
    '/Convert/ConvertFileToPdf'
  end

  def save_path
    @save_path ||= File.join(File.dirname(file), "#{File.basename(file, ".*")}.pdf")
  end

  def call_api
    client.multipart_post(
      path,
      file_name: File.basename(file),
      file: File.open(file, 'rb'),
    ) do |request|
      download(request, save_path)
    end
  end
end
```

[failing test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79XVL.png)

Comment: Well for starters you can just use `File.path` instead of that mess.

Answer (score 0):

While executing the presence check for `save_path`, the corresponding reader method will be invoked.
During this, if `file` isn't filled in with a valid value, the composition from `File.dirname` will fail.

You should probably add a guard clause to your `save_path` method:

```
def save_path
   return if file.nil?
   @save_path ||= File.join(File.dirname(file), "#{File.basename(file, ".*")}.pdf")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how do I pass a valid value for 'file' through the specs? I have been struggling with this and your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Just take any file from your project. If you require a specific type of file, you could place it into a folder like `spec/fixtures` and reference it from there.
When setting up the spec, you can pass it in as part of your `subject` block. I.e. `subject { ConvertFileToPdf.new(file: File.new(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'test1.pdf'))) }`

Comment: I did like this in my spec ,                                                                            `describe 'validations' do
    subject {
      Pdf4me::ConvertFileToPdf.new(file: File.new(File.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'sample.txt')))
    }
    it { should validate_presence_of :file }
  end`                                                                                                                            but i still get 'file' value as nil in my save_path method. I didn't use 'Rails.root.join' as this is a strictly ruby project. **Once again thank you**

Comment: Sorry, since the post is tagged as `ruby-on-rails`, I had assumed that it was a Rails project. Does your `Base` class support passing in an attribute hash then? Otherwise you might need to implement this in your initializer, so it assigns the instance variable `@file`. Also, check what your current directory is. For debugging purposes you can check the output of `File.exist?(...)`. Also, I'd recommend using `pry` and `pry-byebug` as excellent debugging tools: a simple `pry.byebug` allows you to inspect the state of your program at any point.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and advice, Its been really helpful